# Pandas - How to append data to a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Likely makes sense to for loop this, but I don't know what Pandas functions to use. I want to take data from one column and append it to another in parenthesis:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A (1) | 1 |
| B (2) | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an apply function that will work for each row:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B'], 'col2': [1, 2]})
df.apply(lambda x: f'{x.col1} ({x.col2})', axis=1)
```

Or you could use a vectorized solution:

```py
df['col1'] + ' (' + df['col2'].astype(str) + ')'
```

Comment: `df['col1'] + ' (' + df['col2'].astype(str) + ')'` idk why I didn't realize this lol